# Please rename[git-stack] to [gitstack]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Can a moderator please rename the tag [git-stack](/questions/tagged/git-stack) to [gitstack](/questions/tagged/gitstack)?

I created the tag, and the lead developer of [GitStack](http://gitstack.com) just sent me an email asking to remove the dash.

Comment: It looks like there is already a [gitstack](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gitstack/info) tag, unless someone just made this change and didn't post an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, hey... I renamed it after seeing your message in chat and forgot to mention it because I was still mostly asleep.

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: *cough* [status-completed] *cough*

Comment: Fine. But now I AM going back to my coffee.